# How to create windows folders from a PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hopefully someone can help me. I'm open to any suggestions, because this is my first time writing more than "Hello, World" with PHP. I am working on writing a commission web application that allows the user to login, and see a dynamic menu based on a list of PDF files in a user folder saved server side tied to their login. The `PHP` script I am writing should check the `MySQL` `InnoDB` database, run the weekly sales report, generate a `PDF` and then add that `PDF` to a directory (if the directory isn't created then it should create the folder for file insertion). I am using `mPDF` for the `PDF` and the creation and insertion works great, but I am struggling getting the `mkdir` to work with my `array`. It runs and then just generates a folder named `Array`. Here's what I have so far:

```
try {
//Create connection
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$con->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$query = "SELECT user_id FROM users;";
$result = $con->query($query);

foreach($result as $value) {
    $filename = './reports/'.$value.'';
    if(!file_exists($filename)) {
        if(!mkdir('./reports/'.$value.'')) {
            die('Failed to create folders...');
        }
    }
}

$con = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e1) {
    echo $e1->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$value` is an array. Try with -

```
/reports/'.$value['user_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
try {
//Create connection
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$con->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$query = "SELECT user_id FROM users;";
$result = $con->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($value = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $filename = './reports/'.$value["user_id"].'';
    if(!file_exists($filename)) {
        if(!mkdir('./reports/'.$value["user_id"].'')) {
            die('Failed to create folders...');
        }
    }
}
}
$con = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e1) {
    echo $e1->getMessage();
}
```